Gmod lua mysql attempt to index global "" (a nil value) (DarkRP)
So i wanted to play gmod after some time and when i looked up server was down. They published the files on web and i am trying to make it work. Now i get an error called: attempt to index global 'ASAPDriver' (a nil value) (not just once, this is used in 13 places and i am getting errors for them too) I don't know much about MySQL and lua so i need your help.
Thank you!
In short:
https://pastebin.com/QxHwz7Cj
One of the lua :
<https://pastebin.com/9GzVKPeH>

(sorry about pastebin i don't know how to paste here)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
